# Android-java Contdition Check error - need some code logic to be corrected

Tags: java, android, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

This is my code of a sample details gathering page,where once the customer enters his details, it will be stored until another reinstall of this application, there is no error in the code and it executes correctly, but the customer is able to move to the next activity without filling out the form

and i tried a bit of condition checks but all those failed, need some help in code logic

```
    package asr.customer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ASRCustomerAppActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button btn;
    ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String first,last,state,city,g;
    int day,month,year;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        File dbtest =new File("/data/data/asr.customer/databases/customerdetail1.db");
        if(dbtest.exists())
        {
          // what to do if it does exist
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this,mapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {

           db=openOrCreateDatabase("customerdetail1.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

            db.setVersion(1);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            final String table_create="CREATE TABLE customer("+"firstname TEXT,"+"lastname TEXT,"+"day INTEGER,"+"gender TEXT,"+"month INTEGER,"+"year INTEGER,"+"city TEXT,"+"state TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(table_create);
            EditText i2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
            first=i2.getText().toString();
            EditText i3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.last1);
            last=i3.getText().toString();

            DatePicker d=(DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date);
            day=d.getDayOfMonth();
            month= d.getMonth()+1;
            year=d.getYear();
            RadioGroup rg= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
            RadioButton r1= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            RadioButton r2= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
            if(r1.isChecked()==true)
            {
            g=r1.getText().toString();
            }
            else
            {
            g= r2.getText().toString();
            }

            EditText i4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
            city=i4.getText().toString();
            EditText i5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
            state=i5.getText().toString();





            }
        }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // what to do if it doesn't exist

        do{
            //  code
            Toast.makeText(ASRCustomerAppActivity.this, "Please Fill The Blank Spaces", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }while((first.equalsIgnoreCase("") || last.equalsIgnoreCase("") || city.equalsIgnoreCase("") || state.equalsIgnoreCase("")));


            values.put("firstname",first);
            values.put("lastname",last);
            values.put("day",day);
            values.put("month",month);
            values.put("year",year);
            values.put("gender",g);
            values.put("city",city);
            values.put("state",state);

            db.insert("customer", null, values);

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this,mapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }



    }
```

Comment: I hit back immediately after a short check of that code. But I think it's good to give you some feedback why. If you give others a bigger amount of code, such as this code here: **Please indent it properly.** Also make use of blank lines to seperate some (logical) blocks. This helps to spot errors and increases readability a lot.

Comment: @alextsc ok friend ill do that now, but try to give me correction in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
while((first.equalsIgnoreCase("") || last.equalsIgnoreCase("") || city.equalsIgnoreCase("") || state.equalsIgnoreCase("")));
```

try this

```
while((first.length==0|| last.length==0 || city.length==0|| state.length==0));
```

and put this inside your onClick

```
 first=i2.getText().toString();
 last=i3.getText().toString();
city=i4.getText().toString();
state=i5.getText().toString();
```

Comment: what is i2,i3,i4,i5 friend??...what i have to replace with that

Comment: instead of declaring EditText i2; in oncreate, declare these variables before oncreate.. so that they will be available throughout the class... i2,i3.. are edittext objects..

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the values inside your onCreate method because the View is not drawn until the window receives focus.

You must do it inside your onClick method in order to make it works like moving this one to buttonClick method :

```
city=i4.getText().toString();
```